# Vaadin : How to set default path for fileupload component?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Can I set default upload path to my vaadin fileupload component ? I would like to set some upload path to my vaadin component. If somebody does not choose to upload any files , my specific file would be uploaded. Can it be possible ?

For instance : I would like to do as

```
 upload.setDefaultFilePath("C:/ax/w.pdf");
```

Comment: I think there has no sense to set in component. You should try to play with some java logics. For instance : `if(upload.getfilePath()==null) {upload.setFilePath("something")}`

Comment: hmmm... but vaadin upload component doesn't have method: setFilePath(...)

Comment: :-) I said you just *for instance*

Comment: I mean try to solve with java . Not with vaadin components.

Comment: Java would be useless, because once the control gets to the server, you have no chance to "pull" a file from the client. And anyway, no browser allows any service to download a file from the local machine if not explicitly acknowledged by the owner

Comment: @Raffaele sorry sir ! I am confuse with *... any service to download a file from the local machine* . OP didn't describe for download.

Comment: The *upload* component is for copying a file from the client to the server, so from the server's point of view it's a download

Comment: @Raffaele Yes , Thanks for your explanation sir. So , I suggested to check from server-side component the value of input file. If user does not choose any file , server-side should be saved some default file to specific location and ignore **upload** component.

Comment: Please, take a look the [Upload API](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Upload.html) and try to understand how it fits in the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limit of the underlying technology, not of Vaadin itself. Browsers don't allow downloaded code to manipulate the content of an input file field, otherwise a malicious site could create a hidden one and silently stole data from the user.

So I don't think you'll ever find a way with Vaadin, either. However, if you target only one browser (or a limited set of) you can try to exercise the browser API itself in a custom extension, if any API exists in the target browser for doing this, and if selecting the file is really such a pain.

Comment: ok, thank you for information. I will try implement my functionality in other way